# NoClassDefFoundError: java.sql.Date when running Play 2.6 using gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, playframework, playframework-2.6

Has anyone had much luck with the play gradle plugin?  I'm trying to run the Play Framework 2.6 starter project.  I can run from SBT fine but I get the following error when I run from gradle:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Date]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:190)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:202)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:117)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$25.onPush(Ops.scala:1194)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:519)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:482)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:
```

I'm using Java 1.8 with the following build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'play'
    id 'idea'
}

def playVersion = "2.6.13"
def scalaVersion = System.getProperty("scala.binary.version", /* default = */ "2.12")

model {
    components {
        play {
            platform play: playVersion, scala: scalaVersion, java: '1.8'
            injectedRoutesGenerator = true

            sources {
                twirlTemplates {
                    defaultImports = TwirlImports.JAVA
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }   
}

dependencies {
    play "com.typesafe.play:play-guice_$scalaVersion:$playVersion"
    play "com.typesafe.play:play-logback_$scalaVersion:$playVersion"
    play "com.h2database:h2:1.4.196"

    playTest "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.6.2"
    playTest "org.awaitility:awaitility:2.0.0"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        name "lightbend-maven-releases"
        url "https://repo.lightbend.com/lightbend/maven-release"
    }   
    ivy {
        name "lightbend-ivy-release"
        url "https://repo.lightbend.com/lightbend/ivy-releases"
        layout "ivy"
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the java_home to use a Java 1.8 version. Apparently, the play gradle plugin expects a java home.

```
export JAVA_HOME=YOUR_JAVA_LOCATION
```

---

```
$ source .bash_profile

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, my $JAVA_HOME was set to my Java 9 path but java/javac were set to Java 8. This was causing my gradle to use the wrong java version. After fixing my $JAVA_HOME, it works correctly.

I'll leave this up in case anyone else runs into this issue.